# Connecting to mysql in ruby produces wrong number of arguments error (4 of 0) - how to debug?

Tags: mysql, ruby, connection, arguments

I'm trying to connect to a hosted MySQL database from my Ruby script.

```
require "rubygems"
require "mysql"

con = Mysql::new('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database')
```

Running this results in:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (4 for 0)

method initialize  in untitled at line 4
method new         in untitled at line 4
at top level       in untitled at line 4
```

My setup:

- Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.4
- Ruby 1.8.7
- mysql (rubygem) 2.8.1
- gem 1.3.7
- MySQL 5.1.26 (hosted)

I've tried using these variants when connecting:

```
con = Mysql.new('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database')
# same as above

con = Mysql.real_connect('host', 'user', 'pass', 'database') 
# output => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘real_connect’ for Mysql:Class
```

Please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `require "rubygems"` line from your script?

Comment: Removing the 'require "rubygems"' produces the 'No such file to load' error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your configuration (I'm running Linux) but [this](http://thinlight.org/2010/05/12/how-to-install-ruby-mysql-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard/) article seems to describe the same problem you're seeing.

Comment: Wauw thanks - running the gem install with the proper architecture arguments did the trick. :)

Comment: Btw: the is no reason to go un/re-install MySQL as the article suggests. Just the gem.